# Pre increment and post increment when put together on a single variable like this (++i)++, it works in c++ but not in c

Tags: c++, c, increment

I initialized a variable i with a value 3, then put a statement (++i)++ in my code. But, in C, it is showing an error "lvalue required as increment operand". But, if I put this similar code in c++, it works and showing double increment with an output 5. However, one of my friends tried on his compiler using c and it gave an output 4.

```
//using c

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=3;
    (++i)++;
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
 //using c++

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=3;
    (++i)++;
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: It's defined to be illegal in C, for the reason you've heard. (The result of `i++` is an rvalue, which the second `++` can't be applied to.)  But C and C++ are different languages, and C++ has different rules.  If you want to avoid confusion, just use `i += 2`.

Comment: Pretty sure this is undefined behavior in C++ anyway. Just because your compiler gets it right doesn't mean that this is correct. In short: don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known to be undefined behavior. Syntactically this program is correct in C++, and the compiler produces some binary code... but the standard allows it to produce ANY code, even something that returns 100 or formats your disk. In real situations you may observe very strange abnormal scenarios, for example the compiler can drop the whole code after your `(++i)++` statement, because the standard allows it to do whatever it wants right after the program enters into the status of UB. In your case that would mean that there would be no output at all (or the program would print "Hello World" instead of the integer value).

I believe that you are just conducting an experiment. The result is: both your compiler and your friend's are correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, it was not an experiment, rather a question on a mini test that created confusion among my friends and me. But, I get it now.